# Limiting data in table based on data driven pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, data-driven-pages

I have a database connection and a table imported to my ArcMap ToC. I am looking to limit the data that I see in the table based on the current data driven attribute. In the table properties there is no 'Data Driven Pages' option so I am trying to build a 'query builder' string that will remove these records. I have tried:

PERIOD = `<dyn type="page" property= period/>`

and:

PERIOD  = `<dyn type="page" property= "period"/>`

But the result is a blank table when I open it. How do I limit the table data according to the value of the data driven page?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to enable a Page Definition Query on the Layer Property. As long as there is a field that contains the same values as those in the Data Driven Pages index layer.

In this example the index layer is MEX_adm1 (Mexican states), the other layer is MEX_adm2 (subdivisions of states). I set the page definition query on MEX_adm2 to only show the ones within the current page. The Index Layer of the Data Driven Pages is MEX_adm1 and there is an attribute for name.

[image]

Comment: I have a table that I am trying to limit the data of, not a layer. My problem is that this table is joined to a layer to provide that layer with the field that is in my index layer. In the layer properties of the feature class joined to the table, the join fields are not available for selection in page definition. This is why I am trying to limit the table data itself. I believe that you have described the 'how to' for generic data driven pages.